# Parse error in codeigniter query.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have in following code error, what is cause?

did is true following query?(how is true it?)

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', %$value_search%)->get('ki_submits'); //line 15
```

> error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\application\models\model_name.php on
>   line 15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', "%$hotel_search%")->get('hotel_submits');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be in double quotes? So the variable gets parsed by PHP. Like this: "%{$hotel_search}%"

Comment: And even better would be a concatenation `'%' + $hotel_search + '%'`.

Comment: @Zenklys '%' + $hotel_search + '%' will give you 0 in php :)